# REST API PATH Create WorkItem not working, code exiting with 0

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using REST API to create a work item using REST API [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item).For this, i need to use Patch request, but this code not working. program exiting with code 0 (0x0).

```
            HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
            {
              var content = "[{'op': 'add','path': '/fields/System.Title', 'value': 'Title' }]";
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                            new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                string URLTest = "https://MyProject.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ProjectName/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=2.0";
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(
                        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "*******", "******"))));
                var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, URLTest)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8,
                        "application/json-patch+json")
                };

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0 (0x0)` This is just debugging message. You can switch that off by right clicking into the output window and uncheck the thread ended message.

build uri using uriBuilder has to work

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(URLTest);
uriBuilder.Scheme = "http";

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uriBuilder.Uri)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8,
                        "application/json-patch+json")
                };
```

Change the asyc method and find the error message

`HttpResponseMessage response = client.Send(request);`//Now you will get the error message

else use `try catch` block

```
       try
       {
              HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
       }
       catch (TaskCanceledException e)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.ToString());
       }
```

Comment: No this is not working :( Issue is after below first line code stops and return 0it does not move ahead.. I guess there is some issue in request.                                      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
var Response = response.Content;

Comment: In HttpClient there is no Send() method :(

Comment: use try catch block and find the TaskCanceledException @SajalMittal

Comment: I already used try-catch block, thing is it does not move to catch block either.. :(